# How can you bind the type of a generic interface to another generic interface?

Tags: java

I am trying to write an interface that has bounds on multiple layers.  As an example, consider the following code:

```
// the bound type on U is unexpected and doesn't compile
public interface CollectionNumberWrapper<T extends Collection<U extends Number>> {
    void setData(T data);

    U sumOfAllNumbersInCollection()
};

public class NumberCollection implements List<AtomicInteger>{

///...implement...

};

public class StringCollection implements Collection<String>{

///...implement...

};

//This should be legal
public class NumberCollectionWrapper implements CollectionNumberWrapper<NumberCollection>{

    @Override
    void setData(NumberCollection data){
    //...
    };

    @Override
    AtomicInteger sumOfAllNumbersInCollection(){
    //...
    }
}

//This should not be legal, the type parameter should be out of bounds
public class StringCollectionWrapper implements CollectionNumberWrapper<StringCollection>{

}
```

Is it possible to be this specific with type bounds in Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, but it'll take a little more work: you must write

```
public interface CollectionNumberWrapper<U extends Number, T extends Collection<U>> { ... }
```

...though for this specific use case, I would omit `T` entirely and simply use `Collection<U>` everywhere.

Comment: Thank you.  I agree that this is an overcomplication for the particular example given.  I'm sad that my contrived end class would have to declare `impliments CollectionNumberWrapper<AtomicInteger, NumberCollection>` with 2 type parameters rather than being able to infer the first type parameter from the 2nd.  

This is mostly an academic question that I was playing around with, not with any real business use case. Seeing it like this helps me understand why it has to be like this, however.